# How to change the size of a css toggle switch

Tags: html, css, toggle

I'm designing an element for a plugin called elementor. This project is really just to help me learn the functionality of developing for wordpress.

What I'm making is a "toggle content" slider that can toggle between text or predefined html. I've used the slider according to this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp
Right Now the size of a switch is very big. I want a small switch. How Can change it? Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class=" switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class=" slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `calc();` or `var();` because **px** you need to rewrite the sizes from zero

Answer (score 3):

I used `calc();` and `var();`, so you don't have to do a lot of work

 Mozilla documentation: [calc() explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) and [var() explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) and [--var: ; explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) .

just change **ONE** value **the height of switch** for change all responsively!!!

```css
* {
    --switch-height: 34px; /* change the value */
      
    /* other code, pls see it then */
}
```

---

if you want a smaller switch, the `8px` default padding, will take a lot of space,

**so I simplified it for you!** just change the `--switch-padding: 8px;` to something smaller...

automatically CSS calculates all things for you, for making the switch *look good* for *all dimensions* :)

the same thing if you want the switch to be bigger, remember to make the padding also bigger (the padding var)

[image]

> I know This is not a site "we-are-doing-your-work.com" but I really want to help you!

**here the complete fixed code:**

```css
* {
  --switch-height: 34px;
  --switch-padding: 8px;
  --switch-width: calc((var(--switch-height) * 2) - var(--switch-padding));
  --slider-height: calc(var(--switch-height) - var(--switch-padding));
  --slider-on: calc(var(--switch-height) - var(--switch-padding));
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--switch-width);
  height: var(--switch-height);
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--slider-height);
  width: var(--slider-height);
  left: calc(var(--switch-padding) / 2);
  bottom: calc(var(--switch-padding) / 2);
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  transform: translateX(var(--slider-on));
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: var(--slider-height);
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: very good answer, thanks anas!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .label{
    background-color: #fea621;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 26px;
    width: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .checkbox{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .checkbox + .label .ball{
    content: url(323329.png);
    background-color: #001e3d;
  }

  .checkbox:checked + .label .ball{
    content: url(flag-ukraine-circle.svg);
    background-color: #001e3d;
    transform: translateX(24px);
  }

  .ball{
    background-color: #001e3d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    transition: transform .2s linear;
  }

.ball:before:checked{
    content: url(flag-ukraine-circle.svg);
    left: 50px;
}

.ball:checked:after{
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox" class="label"> 
        <i class="ukraine"></i>
        <i class="usa"></i>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can change the size by changing the css

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(16px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(16px);
  transform: translateX(16px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class=" switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class=" slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

try to experiment with different widths and heights